# Kotlin spring-boot @ConfigurationProperties

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, configurationproperty

I'm trying to create the following bean `AmazonDynamoDBAsyncClientProvider`. I've application.properties that defines `endpoint` and `tablePrefix` which I'm trying to inject using `@ConfigurationProperties`

Following is the code snippet for the same. When I run my spring-boot app it doesn't work.

I've tried doing the same `ConfigurationProperties` class using a regular java class which does set those properties but when it comes to `AmazonDynamoDBAsyncClientProvider`, the properties are empty. What am I missing here?

```
@Component
open class AmazonDynamoDBAsyncClientProvider @Autowired constructor(val dynamoDBConfiguration: DynamoDBConfig){

@Bean open fun getAmazonDBAsync() = AmazonDynamoDBAsyncClientBuilder.standard()
        .withEndpointConfiguration(
                AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration(dynamoDBConfiguration.endpoint, dynamoDBConfiguration.prefix))
        .build()
}
```

here is the kotlin bean that I'm trying to autowire with configuration

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(value = "dynamo")
open class DynamoDBConfig(var endpoint: String="", var prefix: String="")
```

finally heres the regular java bean that does get populated with `ConfigurationProperties` but when it gets `Autowired` I see those properties being empty/null

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties("dynamo")
public class DynamoDBConfiguration {
private String endpoint;
private String tablePrefix;

public String getEndpoint() {
    return endpoint;
}

public void setEndpoint(String endpoint) {
    this.endpoint = endpoint;
}

public String getTablePrefix() {
    return tablePrefix;
}

public void setTablePrefix(String tablePrefix) {
    this.tablePrefix = tablePrefix;
}
}
```

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "When I run my spring-boot app it doesn't work."? What's the error message logged if any?

Comment: "When I run my spring-boot app it doesn't work.", I meant when I run my Kotlin app using the SpringBoot Application and if I log `getAmazonDBAsync` in there, I see the two properties are empty/null, when I use the regular java class for properties.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried getting rid of the @Component annotation on your ConfigurationProperties class?

Here is what I have done with Kotlin and Spring, hope it helps.

I am trying to leverage the kotlin-spring and kotlin-allopen gradle plugin

```
dependencies {
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-noarg:$kotlinVersion"
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-allopen:$kotlinVersion"
}
apply plugin: 'kotlin-spring'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-noarg'
noArg {
    annotation("your.noarg.annotation.package.NoArg")
}
```

They do make spring development with kotlin a lot easier.

```
@ConfigurationProperties("dynamo")
@NoArg
data class DynamoDBConfiguration(var endpoint: String, var prefix: String)
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your configuration class and it gets populated. I think your mistake is in the way you are trying to create the bean, the function needs to be in a class annotated with `@Configuration`, this should work:

```
@Configuration
class Beans {
    @Bean
    fun getAmazonDBAsync(config: DynamoDBConfiguration) = 
        AmazonDynamoDBAsyncClientBuilder.standard()
        .withEndpointConfiguration(
            AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration(config.endpoint, config.prefix)
        )
        .build()
}
```

Spring will inject the config for you, as long as you annotate the config with `@Component`, like you did above.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and fixed it this way:

I defined the configuration properties `class` with `lateinit` vars:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "app")
open class ApplicationConfigProperties {
     lateinit var publicUrl: String
}
```

Then configured a bean in my spring boot application:

```
@SpringBootApplication
open class Application {
     @Bean open fun appConfigProperties() = ApplicationConfigProperties()
}
```